# Is it possible to use a class-level custom constraint annotation for two different classes

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, javabeans

I have next constraint **annotation**:

```
@Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PhoneOrEmailPresentedValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface PhoneOrEmailPresented {

    String message() default "Either phone or email should be presented";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And the **validator**:

```
public class PhoneOrEmailPresentedValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PhoneOrEmailPresented, RequestDto> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(RequestDto value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String email = value.getEmail();
        String phone = value.getPhone();

        return (email != null && !email.isEmpty()) ||
               (phone != null && !phone.isEmpty());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(PhoneOrEmailPresented constraintAnnotation) {
        // NOP
    }
}
```

I would like to use this annotation on another DTO which has the same fields that are presented in `isValid()` method.

Is it possible without extracting an interface for get methods?

Answer (score 0):

As no way in validation API were found the issue were solved using reflection (with help of class `org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils`, the same can be done with Java as well):

```
        String email, phone;

        try {
            Field emailField = FieldUtils.getField(value.getClass(), "email", true);
            Field phoneField = FieldUtils.getField(value.getClass(), "phone", true);
            email = (String) emailField.get(value);
            phone = (String) phoneField.get(value);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```